# Android custom view shows up even if all source files are deleted

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-custom-view

Using `SherlockActionBar` I wrote a custom `actionProviderClass` (a spinner) for one of the action bar items.

I decided I don't need it and deleted all the files for it as well as the `actionProviderClass` attribute in the menu file.  I even removed the spinner's values from strings.xml.

However, if I switch to horizontal orientation, the damn thing still shows up.  I tried a fresh emulator as well as a device and it still happens.  I also cleaned the project in Eclipse.

I guess something is being cached somewhere, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can't see why you got a downvote, so +1 to restore the natural balance of the Androidverse.  Try deleting the "bin" and "out" folders, then clean, then build again.

Comment: @Simon by out you mean the gen folder?

Comment: Sorry, yes I do.  It's early o'clock where I am ;)

Comment: @Simon sadly that didn't help.

Comment: Hah, so this turns out to be highly weird.  It isn't an eclipse bug but an SherlockActionBar "[issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/427)" where tabs are being folded into a spinner - which was exactly what my custom actionprovider was doing.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear you found it.  May I suggest that you answer and accept your own question in case someone else comes searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User error here.

SherlockActionBar will collapse tabs into a spinner sometimes even though there is space for views